# Web app with "off-line" mode?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, local-storage, offline

I  am designing an application that must work regardless of whether or not there is an Internet connection. Most of the time (90%), there will be an Internet connection, in which case it will behave like normal. However some of the time the user will not have Internet, in which case I would like to store all their in-session data to the file system, and whenever an Internet connection becomes available again, allow the user to synchronize the saved data from there disk with the backend server.

My thinking was to have a single-page web app that compiles down to a JS file and in "online mode" gets served up from a web server. But in "offline mode", the user will have to have the JS file saved locally to their machine, and then open it in a browser.  The app could auto-detect what mode it is in and either save data to the server (via AJAX) in online mode, or save the data to HTML5 local storage in offline mode.

**Is this feasible, or is my total approach incorrect?**

The only caveats I can see with it are:

- Limited to browsers with HTML5 Local Storage capabilities, but I'm fine with that
- Limited to the size of the HTML 5 Local Storage available on the machine

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at backbone.js.

Comment: Did you do any research? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline

Comment: Your approach seems to be the good one, but as suggested by Diodeus, there must exists some frameworks already implementing this functionality. Concerning the size of the local storage, that's indeed to take into account, so you better watch out the size of your data...